# How can I get a IP of the local interface that directly connects to a default GW

Tags: android, vpn, tun

-Environment-

1. VPN connection(OpenVPN)
   -Default gateway is changed into VPN server IP
   -Virtual interface(tunXX) for VPN connection directly connects to a default gateway
2. Interfaces & default gateway

   > ```
   > interfaces :
   >   lo        inet addr:127.0.0.1
   >   wlan0     inet addr:150.149.131.5
   >   tun0      inet addr:10.8.0.14
   >
   > default gateway : 10.8.0.2
   > ```

In this environment, **I want to know "10.8.0.14"** regardless of the interface name using Android API.

I cound find only a way to get default route IP address below

```
mSocket = new Socket(dstAddress, peerPortNum); 
mStrMyIPAddr = mSocket.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress();
```

But, I don not want to use Socket